# How to make ScrollView refreshable swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

With Swiftui 3 Apple added modifier refreshable. I can use it with List. But if I have scrollview it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: gridSpacing) {
            ForEach($products, id: \.self) { product in
                CardView()
            }
        }
    }.refreshable {
        
    }
```

Comment: Use it on ForEach.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72453592/12299030?