# SwiftUI : How I can set refreshable for my Scrollview without List

Tags: api, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = NewsViewModel()
    
    let dataService = NewsDataService.instance
    
    init() {
        dataService.apiCall(text: "Korea")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                SearchView()
                VStack {
                    Divider()
                        if let newsArray = vm.newsArray?.articles {
                            ForEach(newsArray) { news in
                                NewsRowView(news: news)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("News")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Hi, I tried to find refresh for my scrollview.
But, most of the examples were capable with List.

As you can see my code, I makde my list with HStack children View.
Because of that, I can't use the ".refreshable" modifier.

So, I want to know how I can set that in my view.

And If I can, I want to see detailed code as well!

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72453592/12299030?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use refreshable like this in your NewsRowView. Keep in mind you would need to make sure you are using `ObservableObject` where necessary so that it will give you the new data once it's updated.

```
.refreshable {
            Task {
                let dataService = NewsDataService.instance
                dataService.apiCall(text: "Korea")                    
            }
}
```