# SwiftUI refreshable (Pull to refresh) is not working at ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                    VStack {
                        if self.viewModel.forms.isEmpty && !self.viewModel.isLoading {
                            Text("No Forms Assigned")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                                .accessibility(label: Text("No forms assigned"))
                        }
                        if self.viewModel.isLoading {
                            ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large).padding(.top, 20)
                        }
                        noFormsScrollView
                        Spacer(minLength: 16).accessibility(hidden: true)
                    }
                    .refreshable {
                        self.refreshData()
                    }
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Forms", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

I am trying to add pull to refresh on my `ScrollView` But it's not not working. I am wondering, what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @koen .refreshable or not working.

Comment: I think it only works on `List`

Comment: Not working for ScrollView?

Comment: It will compile fine but not do anything. aheze is right, it only works on List.

Comment: @atultw I got. what show i do from ScrollView?

Comment: You would need to look into something with UIViewRepresentable or a SwiftUI hack. Lots of questions about that on SO

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72453592/12299030?

Comment: This should now be working for most (any?) views since iOS 15. I'm using it for LazyVStack inside of a scrollview. But it has a 33%ish bug with notchless iPhones like 8 and SE.

Comment: "It's not working" is not a useful description. Please make sure to describe what IS happening. Not what isn't happening. "It's not working" can mean anything.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like in iOS 16+ you could do:

```
ScrollView {
    // view body
}
.refreshable {
    // refresh action
}
```

source:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/refreshaction
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707510

The sources do say that this thing is 15+, but it does not seem to work on 15, even though it does not complain at compile time.

Comment: Indeed `.refreshable{}` seems to have no effect on iOS 15. iOS 16, iOS 17 have better results so far.

Answer (score 4):

Pull to refresh is only automatically available on `List` when using [refreshable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/refreshaction). To make any other view refreshable, you will need to write your own handler for that.

[This StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65100922/176160) shows how to make pull to refresh work on a ScrollView.

Comment: Too complicated example ;) - native would be much simpler https://stackoverflow.com/a/72453592/12299030.

Comment: I thought they recently made it available to ScrollView and any other view

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/refreshable(action:)

Answer (score 0):

Complete SwiftUI Example

Simply create  `RefreshableScrollView` in your project

```
public struct RefreshableScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content
    var onRefresh: () -> Void

    public init(content: @escaping () -> Content, onRefresh: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.content = content()
        self.onRefresh = onRefresh
    }

    public var body: some View {
        List {
            content
                .listRowSeparatorTint(.clear)
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .refreshable {
            onRefresh()
        }
    }
}
```

then use `RefreshableScrollView` anywhere in your project

example:

```
RefreshableScrollView{
    // Your content
} onRefresh: {
    // do something you want
}
```

Comment: Hello, it cannot support iOS 13+ since .refreshable { ) requires iOS 15+

Comment: replace your completion to 
var onRefresh:  @Sendable () async -> Void

Comment: this is simply using a List, if you want to do that scrap this code and use List straight, also List will not work on horizontal scrollview !!

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! ScrollView is refreshing fine on the device or simulator, but it's crashing the app when .refreshable called if refreshing logic also updates any Published var in the Observed viewModel. Have no idea why, but I've found that it is not crashing with List)) So, this solution is just so perfect and simple. I've just removed onRefresh from there which is unneeded because standard .refreshable works just fine cuz it's anyway an Environment.

Answer (score 0):

in my project I needed some functions from UIScrollView, so I created this. It allows you to read scrollview offset, dragging end and define on refresh action. It's little bit hacky.. It extract UIScrollView from SwiftUI ScrollView:

```
import SwiftUI

/// Extracting UIScrollview from SwiftUI ScrollView for monitoring offset and velocity and refreshing
public struct ScrollDetector: UIViewRepresentable {
    public init(
        onScroll: @escaping (CGFloat) -> Void,
        onDraggingEnd: @escaping (CGFloat, CGFloat) -> Void,
        onRefresh: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        self.onScroll = onScroll
        self.onDraggingEnd = onDraggingEnd
        self.onRefresh = onRefresh
    }

    /// ScrollView Delegate Methods
    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        init(parent: ScrollDetector) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            parent.onScroll(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        }

        public func scrollViewWillEndDragging(
            _: UIScrollView,
            withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
            targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>
        ) {
            parent.onDraggingEnd(targetContentOffset.pointee.y, velocity.y)
        }

        public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let velocity = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.view)
            parent.onDraggingEnd(scrollView.contentOffset.y, velocity.y)
        }

        @objc func handleRefresh() {
            parent.onRefresh()

            refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        }

        var parent: ScrollDetector

        /// One time Delegate Initialization
        var isDelegateAdded: Bool = false
        var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?
    }

    public var onScroll: (CGFloat) -> Void
    /// Offset, Velocity
    public var onDraggingEnd: (CGFloat, CGFloat) -> Void
    public var onRefresh: () -> Void

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    public func makeUIView(context _: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            /// Adding Delegate for only one time
            /// uiView - Background
            /// .superview = background {}
            /// .superview = VStack {}
            /// .superview = ScrollView {}
            if let scrollview = uiView.superview?.superview?.superview as? UIScrollView, !context.coordinator.isDelegateAdded {
                /// Adding Delegate
                scrollview.delegate = context.coordinator
                context.coordinator.isDelegateAdded = true

                /// Adding refresh control
                let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
                refreshControl.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
                scrollview.refreshControl = refreshControl
                context.coordinator.refreshControl = refreshControl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it in SwiftUI:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack {
       // content here
    }
    .background {
         ScrollDetector(onScroll: { _ in }, onDraggingEnd: { _, _ in }, onRefresh: {
             print("Refresh action")
          })
    }
}
```