# Customisable SwiftUI Refresh spinner

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui, ios15

I currently have a simple SwiftUI ScrollView that contains a single element. I have added the `.refreshable(action: )` property to allow (pull down) refreshing of the view. However, this will only display the default grey spinner when pulling to refresh. Is there a way that I can change the color/style of the spinner?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Add onAppear to your List and place

```
  .onAppear {
                        UIRefreshControl.appearance().tintColor = .green
                        UIRefreshControl.appearance().attributedTitle = NSAttributedString("Refreshing…")
                    }
```

Comment: UIRefreshControl.appearance().attributedTitle = NSAttributedString("Refreshing…") works but causes a memory leak problem. I use the same approach is I have two leaks

Answer (score 0):

I want to add my approach, is a very unorthodox one and I'm not saying is "the" solution, just something to discuss, hopefully it helps someone to "test" and find a better angle.

- Also I only tested this on iOS15, not working on iOS16

1. Make your content inside a list which will give you the .refreshable modifier and will allow pull to refresh: [SWIFTUI refreshable (Pull to refresh) is not working at ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562594/swiftui-refreshable-pull-to-refresh-is-not-working-at-scrollview)
2. Make a singleton of your UIView (this is highly unusual, but for this case may work)

   ```
    class SingletonView: UIView { 
    // Singleton instance
        static let shared : UIView = 
    SingletonView.sharedInstance(size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))

        // You can modify argument list as per your need.
        class private func sharedInstance(size : CGSize)->UIView {
            //Putting the view in the middle, but the details falls on you.
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 10, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
      //just so you can see something
        view.backgroundColor = .red
            return view
        }
   }
   ```
3. Finally add this singleton view to your refresh controller and hide the original:

   ```
    .onAppear{
   //Hide the default refresh controller, attach our uiView
        //Because is a singleton it wont be added several times
        //You can always expand your singleton to be hidden, animated, removed, etc.
   UIRefreshControl.appearance().tintColor = .clear


   UIRefreshControl.appearance().addSubview(SingletonView.shared)

    }
   ```

[image: swiftui scrollable view with custom refresh control]

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Wilsonilo/309600c62c9e27385dfa5296e696b668