# SwiftUI Refreshable With Custom Loading View

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, refreshable

I have a refreshable Scroll View using `.refreshable` and it works exactly how I need it to except for the loading view. How can I hide or replace that loading wheel?

```
    .refreshable {
        Task {
           // Reload
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can't change the appearance of `refreshable` properly, although there are some workarounds (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72026893/customisable-swiftui-refresh-spinner - I never tried ay of these). But you can define your own custom refresh behavior. Read "Refreshing custom views" on this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/refreshaction