# Customize Swift Refreshable View in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, asynchronous, swiftui

I want to use swifts refreshable modifier on a scroll view, however I don't want the default loading icon. How can I hide this so I can display my own, is there also a way to show the loading icon for a couple seconds even after the drag is done?

I couldn't find any modifiers or built in methods to do so. I think adding a clear tint may work but this causes other problems.

```
import SwiftUI
   struct ContentView: View {
       var body: some View {
           ScrollView {
               RefreshableView()
           }
           .refreshable { 
               //some action
           }
       }
   }

   struct MyProgress: View {
       @State private var isProgress = false
       var body: some View {
           HStack{
                ForEach(0...4, id: \.self){index in
                     Circle()
                           .frame(width:10,height:10)
                           .foregroundColor(.red)
                           .scaleEffect(self.isProgress ? 1:0.01)
                           .animation(self.isProgress ? Animation.linear(duration:0.6).repeatForever().delay(0.2*Double(index)) :
                                .default
                           , value: isProgress)
                }
           }
           .onAppear { isProgress = true }
           .padding()
       }
   }

   struct RefreshableView: View {
       @Environment(\.refresh) private var refresh

       @State private var isRefreshing = false

       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               if isRefreshing {
                   MyProgress().transition(.scale)
               }
           }
           .animation(.default, value: isRefreshing)
           .background(GeometryReader {
               Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: -$0.frame(in: .global).origin.y)
           })
           .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
               if $0 < -80 && !isRefreshing {
                   isRefreshing = true
                   Task {
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72026893/5133585